# How to execute a function in ternary operator

Tags: php, html

I want create a navigation list by some `if` `else` statement. Below is what I intend to do:

```
$v='p';
......
......
some codes go here
......
$menu1 ='<li><a href="#">Market</a>'.$v==='p' ? set_submenu('market'):''.'</li>';
.........
........

echo $menu1;
```

what the line do, if the `$v` is `p` then it add a submenu of market, which has some other submenus. If the $v is other than 'p', then it just create menu only and no sub-menu. But this is not happening, nothing is outputting. But if I break it in three lines like:

```
$menu1 ='<li><a href="#">Market</a>';
$menu1 .= $v==='p' ? set_submenu('market'):'';
$menu1 .= '</li>';
```

Then the menu with submenu is showing. But for cleaner code, I want to do it in single line. How can I concatenate those in a single line of code?

Comment: At where or in which point of code?

Comment: Let's think it through: creating the $menu1 string in three separate steps worked, right? Why do you think it works differently than doing it all in one big statement?

Comment: I did not think, rather I knew that it was due to my coding mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$menu1 = '<li><a href="#">Market</a>' . ($v === 'p' ? set_submenu('market') : '') . '</li>';
```

Answer (score -1):

You have not used the correct syntax with your ternary, parenthesis are needed around your condition. I tested the below and it worked.

```
$menu1 ='<li><a href="#">Market</a>'.($v == 'p') ? set_submenu('market'):''.'</li>';
```